# How to insert data into database using asp,net mvc and stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I'm using stored procedure to insert data into a table database; however whenever I do a button, the data is not sent to the database. In addition; I would like to give an error if nothing was entered in the database or success message saying that it was entered. Not sure how to insert data into the database; what did I leave out

**Form**

```
<h2>Requisition Screen</h2>


{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Request Item</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.reqDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.reqDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "reqDate", @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.reqDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    </div>


   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.count, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })
       <text> @Html.Encode(Model.items.Count()) </text>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.reqNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.reqNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "reqnum", @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.reqNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.department, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })

        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.department, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.department, new SelectList(Model.departmentsList, "Text", "Value"), new { @id = "department", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.department, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeeDetails, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })
        @*@Html.Label("Requested by:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })*@
        @if (Model.department == null)
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.employeeDetails.employeeNum, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), new { @id = "empname", @class = "form-control" })
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.employeeDetails.employeeNum, new SelectList(ViewBag.ReceivedByReps, "Value", "Text"), "select", new { @id = "empname", @class = "form-control" })
        }

        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.employeeName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeeDetails.employeeNum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


    </div>


    @*@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.employeeDetails.employeeNum, new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)TempData["company_dd3"], "Value", "Text"), "select", new { @class = "form-control" })*@

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.employeeDetails.firstName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.employeeDetails.lastName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.employeeDetails.Name)




    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Enter Requested Item(s)</h4>

            <hr />

            <div class="Row form-group">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, null, new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "itemNumber", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.description, null, new { @id = "description", @class = "form-control" })
                    @*<font color="blue">Please use your keyboard arrow keys to select items</font>*@
                    @*  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item.description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @id = "txtItem" })*@
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                   <font color="red">@ViewBag.errorMessage</font>
                </div>
            </div>

            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.item.lineNum)




            <div class="Row  form-group">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.price, new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "price", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.expense_account, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3" })
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.item.expense_account.index, new SelectList(Model.accountlist, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.expense_account, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                </div>


                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.item.selecteduomtext, new { @id = "selecteduomtext" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.item.lineNum)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.items)


                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3" })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item.quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.inventory_account, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })  

                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.UofM, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3" })
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.item.UofM, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Text", "Value"), new { @id = "uofm", @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.UofM, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>



                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-12">

                        <input type="submit" value="Add" name="Add" class="btn btn-default" width="89" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                        <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="Cancel" margin="50px" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Cancel", "Requisition")' " class="btn btn-default" />


                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <table id="myTable">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-md-2">Item Number</th>
                            <th class="col-md-2">Item Description</th>
                            <th class="col-md-3">Expense Account</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">Quantity</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">UOM</th>

                            <th class="col-sm-1">Item Price</th>


                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        @{

                                if (@Model.items.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    foreach (var item in @Model.items)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="col-md-3">@item.itemNumber</td>
                                            <td class="col-md-2">@item.description</td>
                                            <td class="col-md-3">@item.expense_account.getDescription</td>
                                            <td class="col-sm-1">@item.quantity.ToString()</td>
                                            <td class="col-sm-1">@item.selecteduomtext</td>

                                            <td class="col-sm-1">@item.price.ToString()</td>



                                            <td>
                                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.lineNum }) |
                                                @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", new { id = item.lineNum }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you would like to remove this item?'); " })
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>


                                }

                            }
                        }


                    </table>


                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-12">


                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        @*<input type="button" value="Finish" name="Issue" margin="50px" onclick="location.href='/Requisition/ViewRequisition' " class="btn btn-default" />*@
                        <input type="button" id="RequestItem" value="Request" name="Request"  class="btn btn-default" />
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult RequestItem(Requisition requisition)
{
    IssueDAO dbdata = new IssueDAO();
    dbdata.connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TWCL_OPERATIONSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    getRequisition.reqDate = DateTime.Now; //Sets the transaction date to current date
    //getIssue.status = -1;
    Item item = new Item();
    try
    {
        dbdata.createRequisition(getRequisition, item);//Creates the issue in the database
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogWrite logWriter = new LogWrite(ex.ToString());
        ViewBag.errorMessage = "Unable to complete the Issue. Please see Log file for more Information";
        return View("RequisitionItem", getRequisition);
    }
    return View("RequisitionItem", getRequisition);
}
```

**createRequisition Function**

```
 public bool createRequisition(Requisition requisition, Item requisitionitem)
{
    int rec_upd = 0;
    bool status;
    using (SqlConnection TWCLOPConnect = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
    {
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
    SqlCommand requestcommand = new SqlCommand();

    //Command to update the requisition table with the header information
    requestcommand.Connection = TWCLOPConnect;
    requestcommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    requestcommand.CommandText = "requisition_sp_createRequestion";
    //issuecommand.Parameters.Add("@docnum", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = issue.docNumber;
    //issuecommand.Parameters.Add("@doctype", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = issue.docType;
    requestcommand.Parameters.Add("@req_num", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = requisition.reqNumber;
    //issuecommand.Parameters.Add("@stores_rep_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = issue.processedbyDetails.employeeNum;
    //issuecommand.Parameters.Add("@dept_rep_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = issue.employeeDetails.employeeNum;
    //issuecommand.Parameters.Add("@inventory_acc_indx", SqlDbType.Int).Value = issue.inventory_acccount;
    requestcommand.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.Int).Value =requisitionitem.description;
    requestcommand.Parameters.Add("@Req_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = requisition.reqDate;
    requestcommand.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.Float);
    //issuecommand.Parameters.Add("@department", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = issue.department;
    //issuecommand.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Int).Value = issue.status;

    //Command to update the issueitem table with details of the transaction 
    command.Connection = TWCLOPConnect;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "createRequestedItem";
    command.Parameters.Add("@req_num", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = requisition.reqNumber;
    //command.Parameters.Add("@inventory_acc_indx", SqlDbType.Int).Value = requisition.inventory_account;
    //command.Parameters.Add("@line_num", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters.Add("@itemnum", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    command.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.Float);
    command.Parameters.Add("@issue_price", SqlDbType.Float);
    command.Parameters.Add("@expense_acc", SqlDbType.Int);
    //command.Parameters.Add("@inventory_acc", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters.Add("@uofm", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    try
    {
        TWCLOPConnect.Open();
        requestcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        foreach (var item in requisition.items)
        {
            //command.Parameters["@line_num"].Value = item.lineNum;
            command.Parameters["@itemnum"].Value = item.itemNumber;
            command.Parameters["@issue_price"].Value = item.price;
            command.Parameters["@qty"].Value = item.quantity;
            command.Parameters["@expense_acc"].Value = item.expense_account.index;
            //command.Parameters["@inventory_acc"].Value = item.inventory_account.index;
            command.Parameters["@uofm"].Value = item.selecteduomtext.Trim();
            rec_upd = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        TWCLOPConnect.Close();
    }
    if (rec_upd > 0)
    {
        status = true;
    }
    else
    {
        status = false;
    }
}
return status;
```

}

**Stored Procedures**

```
      CREATE PROCEDURE createrequesteditem
            @expense_acc varchar(50),
            @quantity_requested int,
            @inventory_acc varchar(50),
            @Req_No varchar(50),
            @unit_of_measure varchar(15), 
            @issue_price float
        AS
        BEGIN
            -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
            -- interfering with SELECT statements.
            SET NOCOUNT ON;

            -- Insert statements for procedure here
            Insert Into RequestedItem Values (
                @expense_acc, 
                @quantity_requested ,
                @inventory_acc ,
                @Req_No ,
                @unit_of_measure, 
                @issue_price );
        END

    CREATE PROCEDURE requisition_sp_createRequisition
            @Req_No varchar(50),    
            @Req_Date datetime,
            @description varchar,
            @quantity int
        AS
        BEGIN
            -- SET 

NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
        -- interfering with SELECT statements.
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        -- Insert statements for procedure here
        INSERT INTO Requisition VALUES (@Req_No,    
        @Req_Date, 
        @description,
        @quantity )
    END
```

Comment: Have you tried `<input type="submit"`?

Comment: Are you seeing any exceptions being thrown when the code gets executed?Can you put the whole form code instead of only the button code in your post? And the table definitions might help as well.

Comment: there was no exception thrown

Comment: when I try to debug it doesn't pick up the function'

Comment: @cChacon; the page just5 refresh with using submit

Comment: Do you mean the `public ActionResult RequestItem(Requisition requisition)` function is not called when you debug? There are a lot of debugging steps you can take to check this. First in the browser, press F12, go to the network tab, press your submit button and see if anything is being posted to your controller.

Comment: I get this warning The code on this page disabled back and forward caching

Comment: That warning is fine. You can ignore it. Now go to the network tab, press your submit button, and see if anything is posted

Comment: Nothing is posted